# Add class to every A tag in string

Tags: php, css, string, replace

just started converting a site into wordpress when I ran into an issue.
I am stripping the default output *Table* down to just the A tags, but sadly wordpress does not put any of the styling information on the A tags (class or id)

```
$menuArgs = array(
     //...Args...
);
echo strip_tags(
    wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ), '<a>' );?>
```

Is there any way to add `class="MenuLink"` to every Echoed A tag easily?? or will I have to use some substr_replace like function  ~

Comment: If i understood well, i think the easier way is to use a "replace all" in a text editor. in order to add a class to all <a> in your page

Comment: so something like `echo str_replace ( '<a>' , '<a class="HeaderNavigation-Button">' , Subject );`

Comment: If you have a class on every single a element in another element, the CSS should just target parent a.

Comment: I was thinking about that... Sadly this is a "wordpress theme" and the clients are not coders... So I was hoping to avoid neededing to change that if they wanted to add more links later

Answer (score 2):

I think it is better to use  a custom walker to add that class. Look
[Cleaner output for wp_nav_menu()](http://www.mattvarone.com/wordpress/cleaner-output-for-wp_nav_menu/)  and  [Improve your Wordpress Navigation Menu Output](http://www.kriesi.at/archives/improve-your-wordpress-navigation-menu-output)  and [T5_Nav_Menu_Walker_Simple — Gist](https://gist.github.com/1053467)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up settling for this instead of Cleaner output just due to lower overall code~

```
           <?php 
                $menuParameters = array(
                    'theme_location' => 'Header Menu (Part1)',
                    'container'       => false,
                    'echo'            => false,
                    'items_wrap'      => '%3$s',
                    'depth'           => 0,
                ); 

            echo str_replace (
                '<a' , '<a class="HeaderNavigation-Button" ' , 
                strip_tags(
                    wp_nav_menu( $menuParameters ),
                '<a>' ) ); 
            ?>
```

If anyone has a cleaner way, please let me know